# Convert pandas dataframe to list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as follows

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

I want to convert this to a list of tuples. I tried using `itertuples()` for the same

```
>>> list(df.T.itertuples())
[('a', 1, 3), ('b', 2, 4)]
```

But, I want the result to be of the format  [('a', [1, 3]), ('b', [2, 4])] wherein the first value of the tuple is the column name and the second item in the tuple is a list of column values.

I know this can be done by looping through all column names and manually constructing the list of tuples. I'm just wondering if there is a smarter way to do this.

Comment: If the values are np arrays is this acceptable? `list(zip(df.columns,df.T.values))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can zip the column names with the values as lists:

```
In [127]:
list(zip(df.columns,df.T.values.tolist()))

Out[127]:
[('a', [1, 3]), ('b', [2, 4])]
```

Comment: How did I forget zip ! Thanks Ed !